# How to check the hardware state of the mouse?

Tags: c#, .net

I want to be able to check if the mouse is down or up ignoring virtual clicks.
I am making a program which spams right clicks when the right click button is held, my program works if i bind the spam right click when the any other button is held. It is not working because it is registering the simulated click as a button down and then up. So it only clicks once until it thinks the mouse isn't held because of the virtual click. 
Also, if you know a program that does this, it would be nice to download it instead.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Click_Manager
{
    class Program
    {
        private static LowLevelMouseProc _proc = HookCallback;
        private static IntPtr _hookID = IntPtr.Zero;
        private static POINT mousePos;

        public static void Main()
        {
            Thread othread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(MouseHandler));
            othread.Start();

            _hookID = SetHook(_proc);
            Application.Run();
            UnhookWindowsHookEx(_hookID);
        }

        public static void MouseHandler()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                MouseButtons pressedButtons = Control.MouseButtons;
                if (pressedButtons == MouseButtons.Right)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("click");
                    mouse_event((uint)MouseEvents.WM_RBUTTONDOWN | (uint)MouseEvents.WM_RBUTTONUP, (uint)mousePos.x, (uint)mousePos.y, 0, 0);
                }
                Thread.Sleep(50);
            }
        }

        private static IntPtr SetHook(LowLevelMouseProc proc)
        {
            using (Process curProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
            using (ProcessModule curModule = curProcess.MainModule)
            {
                return SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, proc,
                    GetModuleHandle(curModule.ModuleName), 0);
            }
        }

        private delegate IntPtr LowLevelMouseProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        private static IntPtr HookCallback(
            int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
        {
            if (nCode >= 0 &&
                MouseMessages.WM_MOUSEMOVE == (MouseMessages)wParam)
            {
                MSLLHOOKSTRUCT hookStruct = (MSLLHOOKSTRUCT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(MSLLHOOKSTRUCT));
                mousePos = hookStruct.pt;
            }
            return CallNextHookEx(_hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
        }

        private const int WH_MOUSE_LL = 14;

        private enum MouseMessages
        {
            WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x0201,
            WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x0202,
            WM_MOUSEMOVE = 0x0200,
            WM_MOUSEWHEEL = 0x020A,
            WM_RBUTTONDOWN = 0x0204,
            WM_RBUTTONUP = 0x0205
        }

        private enum MouseEvents
        {
            WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x02,
            WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x04,
            WM_RBUTTONDOWN = 0x08,
            WM_RBUTTONUP = 0x10
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private struct POINT
        {
            public int x;
            public int y;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private struct MSLLHOOKSTRUCT
        {
            public POINT pt;
            public uint mouseData;
            public uint flags;
            public uint time;
            public IntPtr dwExtraInfo;
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook,
            LowLevelMouseProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        private static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode,
            IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern void mouse_event(uint dwFlags, uint dx, uint dy, uint cButtons, uint dwExtraInfo);

    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of adding a program, the correct way is to *remove* a program.  The one that spams virtual clicks.  Also the usual fate of software like this, make sure your uninstaller works well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the mouse handler events you cannot differentiate "hardware" and "software" clicks. The mouse driver generates the very same events, which you can create programmatically by a `SendMessage`, for example. The "low level" events are nothing more than capturing these soft events globally, which you can then map down to your controls or whatever.

So if you want to achieve that, you should write you own API to ask the physical signals via an USB, PS2 or RS-232 physical interface.

But what do you mean "hardware state" in a VM? Or in an online application? Google, for example, has chosen another way [to differentiate real and soft clicks](https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2014/12/05/i-am-not-a-robot-google-swaps-text-captchas-for-quivery-mouse-clicks/): instead of trying to use any "low-level access" (whatever it means), they detect whether the mouse move and click seems natural or is too regular, which can be a sign that the click is invoked by a software.